# Last change of page (page settings && page content) tstamp/SYS_LASTCHANGED

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I want do display the date of the last update of a page. This should include changes on the page entity itself (pages) as also changes made on the content of the page (`tt_content`).

As stated in different posts the attribute `SYS_LASTCHANGED` could be used, but this works only for changes made on the page entity not its related content. Is there any (custom - hooks? - events?) solution to reflect all changes made to the page and its content?

Comment: there should be a updated_at timestamp (UNIX timestamp) for every record?

Answer (score 1):

The value for `SYS_LASTCHANGED` is computed on page generation (and not on any change of records in a page) if the page cache is set.

Especially if you are logged in to the backend the page cache is not set.
So you need an independent browser window to fetch the page and fill the page cache to set the value after you changed any content of that page.